# ASP.NET Core MVC - InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting the apparently classic exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'PieShop.ViewModels.HomeViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PieShop.Models.Pie]'

when trying to render a page in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I've seen a lot of answers for this question, but all seem to be the result of an obvious datatype mismatch between what's passed into the view from the controller and what's declared in the view itself. In my case, they match perfectly. Here's my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPieRepository pieRepository;

    public HomeController(IPieRepository pieRepository)
    {
        this.pieRepository = pieRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var pies = pieRepository.GetAllPies();

        var vm = new HomeViewModel()
        {
            SomeData = "haiod",
            Title = "Welcome to the Pie Shop"
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Here's the view model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the view (which is called `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model PieShop.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

<h1>@Model.SomeData</h1>
```

The model passed into the view from the controller and what the view is declaring as its model are *clearly* the exact same type. What gives?

Comment: What is the view file name?

Comment: For debugging purpose remove the `@model` declaration at the top and write at the page `<h1>@Model.GetType()<h1>`. Now you can see the exact type passed onto your view and check if it is correct. Maybe you have declared the same type name in two different namespaces or something similar.

Comment: From the code , there is really no problem. You need to confirm that your current view and Index action correspond to each other. You can try to recreate a new action and corresponding view to retest.

Comment: I've added the name of the view to the original question. I can confirm that they do correspond to each other, because when I pass a different type to the view, I can get things to render just fine. When I try to render the type with ```<h1>@Model.GetType()</h1>```, I just get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had declared a type for the model in the shared `_Layout.cshtml` because I copy/pasted it during some refactoring:

`@model IEnumerable<PieShop.Models.Pie>`

So... just a copypasta error :facepalm: